# Use row values as data frame headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I am dealing with several data frames (`DataFrames = [DataFrame_a,b,c...z]`) with long description as their headers, for examples, `a = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,7],["A","B","C"],[5,6,0]], columns = ['SuperSuperlong name columnA', 'SuperSuperlong name columnB','SuperSuperlong name columnC'])`

```
   SuperSuperlong_name_columnA     SuperSuperlong_name_columnB    SuperSuperlong_name_columnC
0         1                                   2                                7 
1         ABC                                 BCD                              CDE 
2         5                                   6                                0
```

I'd like it to be transformed to

```
          ABC                                 BCD                              CDE 
0 SuperSuperlong_name_columnA     SuperSuperlong_name_columnB    SuperSuperlong_name_columnC
1         1                                   2                                7
2         5                                   6                                0
```

What's the easiest way?

I also like to apply the method to all data frame I have. How should I do it?

Comment: Try this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957964/convert-header-into-row

Comment: Are these dataframes coming from a file, or some other program that you have no control over? Also I'd suggest not having the first row be the string, as it will upcast everything to `object` which will only make your life more difficult down the road. You could use a `MultiIndex` on the columns, or just store that information in  another lookup table for the easiest solution

Comment: @ALollz these Data frames are Excel files I have imported as data frame that I wouldn't want to change. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
# Pass column name as new value in DataFrame and reset index
df.loc['new'] = df.columns
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

# Pass the row you want as the column name
df.columns = df.iloc[1]
```